# Event listener in python script on a server

Tags: python, event-listener

I want to write a python script to run on a server that will be checking for changes on a database (e.g. total number of records), and when one occurs it will perform an action.

I am new in python and I don't know how I should approach this, is there a proposed event listening methodology to optimize cpu consumption and ensure smooth running?

I'm not asking for specific code but more like the high-level idea.

EDIT: After KT.'s helpful response I built this code to implement a listener for changes in a json response from a URI api:

```
import json
import time
import requests

class Test():

    def __init__(self):
        self.total_services = self.__get_total_services()

    def __get_total_services(self):
        url = "my_url_that_responds_with_json"
        response = requests.get(url)
        json_data = response.json()
        dict_data = json.loads(json.dumps(json_data))
        total = len(dict_data['services'])
        return total

    def listen_for_changes(self):
        while 1:
            if (self.__get_total_services() != self.total_services):
                self.total_services = self.__get_total_services()
                """do something"""
            time.sleep(60)
        return 0



my_test = Test()
my_test.listen_for_changes()
```

My question is should this code run somehow in the background or it is ok to run it like this from my server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, there are two ways you can detect changes in the database (or anywhere else, in fact):

- **Polling** - query the database regularly from your code and detect changes in your Python code. This approach is simple and straightforward, although it may indeed be a bit wasteful on the resources, if you poll too frequently.
- **Notifications** - configure the database to track changes and notify your application. This method might seem more reasonable in terms of resource usage, but it is may turn out to be so annoying and messy to implement that you would not want to go this way unless you are forced to.
  In the most general case this approach will require you to:

  - Decide on a way to notify your application (e.g. keep a network socket open, listen to OS signals, track an open file or a pipe, etc).
  - Implement a [trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/faqs-triggers.html) in the database that will react to row insertions or deletions and invoke the notification process (e.g. execute a script that will send a message to your server).
  - If your application and the database server run on different machines, you might need to think about having a queue inbetween to make sure the notifications are not lost in transit.

  Alternatively, if your database is only changed from one other application, you can configure *that* application to send you notifications whenever something changes. If your database does not support triggers, this may be your only chance (if any) to implement the notification-based solution.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I think I'll go with polling, notfications seem too complicated. Do you recommend an infinite loop with some sleep time for this implementation?

Comment: The infinite loop with a fixed sleep time is the simplest thing to try indeed.